# Is OpenHardwareMonitor  reliable when used with c# ?

Tags: c#

What I mean is that I didn't find any other source code for c# of other programs that monitor the hardware on the pc.
I wonder if the values that I am getting from the openHardwareMonitor are relaible enough?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can also try with this code plex library and compare results

http://managedupnp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

there are few people do the things in C#, they use C++, C, or VB.
so if you want to do this, you can try the windows APIs.
by the way, it's easy to call the windows APIs in C#